# Permissões de usuário

Tags: sql-server

Estou com uma dificuldade em configurar as permissões de um usuário no sql server:

Hoje eu tenho um usuário que atualmente é o `db_owner`, eu quero tirar esse acesso dele, mas eu preciso que esse usuário tenha acesso total para `procedures` e `functions`, e ao mesmo tempo que ele tenha somente acesso de consulta em tabelas normais, como posso fazer essa configuração?

Answer (score 2):

- Remova do usuário o grupo `db_owner`;
- Adicione o grupo `db_datareader` para que tenha permissão de `SELECT`;
- Adicione permissão específica de `EXECUTE` nas procedures que deseja que ele execute.

Exemplo:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON nome_storedprocedure TO login_usuario
```

Comment: e tem como selecionar todas as proceures? 
Pq sao mais de 2 mil por databases

Comment: se for de um em um vai demorar muito

Comment: você pode dar permissão de execute para todo o banco, que irá permitir executar todas as procedures: `GRANT EXECUTE TO login_usuario` ou no *squema*, por exemplo no `dbo` desse jeito: `GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA ::dbo TO login_usuario`

Comment: ai ele vai conseguir dar update, alter e etc em todas as procedures?

Comment: as procedures continuam com um cadeado  de bloqueadas rodando o script , so desbloqueiam se eu for na role do database e liberar, mas fazer isso de uma ha uma fica inviável, pois sao muitas

Comment: se der permissão no schema funciona, mas você pode fazer algo mais elegante: cria uma nova role: `CREATE ROLE db_execproc`, adicione essa permissão para o usuário, e por fim dê permissão de execute no banco de dados para a nova role: `GRANT EXECUTE ON DATABASE::nome_database TO db_execproc`

Comment: Mas as procedures ainda continuam com o cadeado ao lado

Comment: Fiz um teste com o DB local e funcionou o execute, não reparei se as procs aparecem com o cadeado vou conferir

Comment: Tentei de inúmeras formas, e não consegui